# How to do up a excel hair chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm trying to do up a chart (on excel), the chart that I have in mind is somewhat similar to the attached picture.

[image]

Data:

- X-axis: dates (weekly data)
- Y-axis: interest rates

Doing this, I can easily create an area chart.

Thereafter, I need to extend each data point on the chart.
say on 24 June 2015, I need to do a 2 year forecast.

How should I arrange my excel data to replicate something similar?

Comment: Good morning,
to better illustrate my point, please see a sample picture (pardon me for my horrible drawings)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6O4-X3A00XZX2RBX0owUjlCYUU/view?usp=sharing

this is somewhat tricky, the blue lines are the projection / forecast
Basically, i need to incorporate the data in this manner.

I deeply appreciate any feedback or advice

Comment: http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/images/user3303/imageroot/2014/03/20140309_fwd.png

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to have each "hair" on your chart be in it's own column.[image: "Hair" Chart with data structure]

This is just a simple scatter plot.  Make sure that your "Select Data" -->"Hidden and Empty Cells" setting is set to *Show empty cells as gaps*

Answer (score 0):

@Cedric  You mentioned 'area' chart, so I present a sample of this type, but the chart type is fairly interchangeable.

You could do a simple date column, with each week displayed, then line up the data along side for your different series of information. See example -

You simply select/highlight the headings and all data below, then Insert the chart type. Excel will work out the series and headings automagically.

[image]